# TYPO3: RealURL on Windows (404 not found)

Tags: windows, iis, typo3

I am using TYPO3 on a Windows 2008 R2 Server with IIS 7.5.

**My problem is:**

Opening the Website in a Browser, my URL is displayed as i wish, but it gives me a 404 Error.

E.g.: Opening www.my-domain.com is correctly displayed as www.my-domain.com/home/. **BUT** the Server can't find the page and throws a **404 Not Found Error.**

However, opening the "standard Typo3 URL", seems to work (www.my-domain.com/index.php?id=2)

The Windows mod_rewrite is working, since i tested it with a web.config a simple redirect. (www.my-domain.com/google redirected me to google.com)

I also tried out several web.config examples I found in the web, but no result.

Somebody knows what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you rename _.htaccess to .htaccess? Does the htaccess work (e.g. you get an error if there is a typo or create a redirect there)?

Comment: i have both a .htaccess and _.htaccess. But i thought in IIS, there is no use of .htaccess, since there is the use of the web.config file? 

The .htaccess, which was generated from typo3 does not work!

Answer (score 0):

You need to rewrite the TYPO3 .htaccess file to web.config file: https://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/translate-htaccess-content-to-iis-webconfig

The most important part of htaccess you need is where it checks weather a file/directory/symlink like in URL exists otherwise it rewrites everything into index.php:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^.*$ %{ENV:CWD}index.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: I already tried to convert my .htaccess into a web.config file with help of an online converter. Still there was no success... I placed the web.config in the ROOT of my webserver (httpdocs), while the Typo3 is in a subfolder (httpdocs/typo3) for test purposes. Is it possible that it does not work because my Typo3 is in a subfolder?

Comment: You should have web.config for that directory or otherwise you need to add the directory name before index.php rewrite rule.

Comment: i have already tried it with the web.config in the /typo/ folder, but that didn't help either. :( I am already despairing about it :D

Comment: And did you try solutions from here? https://wiki.typo3.org/Windows#Rewriting_URLs

Comment: Not really, because i don't have the ISAPI. At least I think so! Where can i check if I have ISAPI Rewrite installed? I only have tried with web.config and that worked for a simple Rewrite. In IIS I can see a "ISAPI filter" but I don't know if that is the right?